# Any reason for choosing t-SNE over UMAP when visualizing?

Tags: data-visualization, unsupervised-learning, tsne

According to the UMAP paper:

> Our algorithm is competitive with t-SNE for visualization quality and arguably preserves more of the global structure with superior run time performance.

- [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426)

It seems to me that UMAP is better when it comes to visualizing.
However is there a reason for choosing t-SNE over UMAP?